# CODEIGNITER: Can't get the page requested

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having problem with CodeIgniter 2. It's returning a 404 Error. Here is my code:

**config/routes.php**

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
$route['default_controller'] = "inventory";
$route['404_override'] = '';

$route['create_item'] = "inventory/createitem";
```

**controllers/inventory.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Inventory extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {

       $this->load->view('inventory/index');

    }

    public function create_item()
    {

       $this->load->view('inventory/createitem');

    }


}
```

**views/inventory/createitem.php**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>    
    <?php $this->load->view('templates/head_inc');  ?>
  </head>

  <body>
    <?php $this->load->view('templates/header_inc');  ?>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">                
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li ><a href="patients.php">Patients</a></li>                                  
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">            
            <li ><a href="createpatient.php">Create New Patient</a></li>                  
          </ul>

          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">            
            <li ><a href="reports.php">Reports</a></li>                      
          </ul>          
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
          <h1 class="page-header">Create New Item</h1>



        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <?php $this->load->view('templates/footer_inc');  ?>

      </body>
</html>
```

I've been researching about this issue and I can't seem to find out.
This is my first time doing PHP Framework.

I am hoping for your great answers.

Comment: What's the URL you're trying to access?

Comment: in your config/routes.php you created $route['create_item'] = "inventory/createitem"; it searches for function createitem whereas your function name is create_item

Comment: @Aaron Alfonso Have you configured your config.php file so `$config['index_page'] = '';` and do you have a htaccess in main directory to suite? If not then you will need to include the index.php in your url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$route['create_item'] = "inventory/create_item";
```

Instead of

```
$route['create_item'] = "inventory/createitem";
```

Because in you collator function name is `create_item()`

> Alternative Solution

Change `function create_item()` into `function createitem()`

Answer (score 1):

```
  <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
   $route['default_controller'] = "inventory";
  $route['404_override'] = '';

    $route['create_item'] = "inventory/create_item";
```

use this in your config as create_item is your function name in inventory controller.

Answer (score 1):

you have used `inventory/createitem` in your controller where it should be the **controller_name/function_name** and route array contain your url param

If you want url like this `http://yoururl.com/inventory/createitem` then you need to add like following:

```
$route['createitem'] = "inventory/create_item";
```

where, **createitem** is url param (you can change whatever you want) and **create_item** should be your function name inside inventory controller.